# Show that $\mathfrak{Re}(\textrm{Li}_2(e^{ix}))=\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi x}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (polylogarithm)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polylogarithm

I am working with the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) and want to find closed expressions for $\textrm{Li}_2(e^{ix})$.

1. If I [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=real%28Li_2%28exp%28i*x%29%29%29) the function $\mathfrak{Re}(\textrm{Li}_2(e^{ix}))$ I get $y=\dfrac{x^2}{4}-\dfrac{\pi x}{2}+\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$ in the interval from 0 to $2\pi$. How can I see this connection?
2. Is there something similar possible for $\mathfrak{Im}(\textrm{Li}_2(e^{ix}))$?

Edit: I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967398/extract-real-and-imaginary-parts-of-operatornameli-2-lefti-left2-pm-sqrt3) but was not able to use it.

Comment: Hi, please put your commented link in the question so it's easier for people to see :)

Comment: The imaginary component of the dilogarithm is equivalent to the [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Relation_to_the_polylogarithm).

Comment: Ok, and the real part of $\text{Li}_2(e^{ix})$ is just the SL-type Clausen function $\text{Sl}_2$, which has a closed form.

Comment: @garondal You can also think about it as a Fourier series.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552640/series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cosnxn2), combined with $$
\Re(\text{Li}_2(e^{ix}))=\Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikx}}{k^2}\right)=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2}.
$$